# RxJava - How to set Observer to block

Tags: multithreading, rx-java

I would like my `Observable` to block until the operation is complete and then continue with the next method calls etc.  Take a look at this code:

```java
import rx.Observable;
import rx.android.schedulers.AndroidSchedulers;
import rx.functions.Action1;
import rx.functions.Func1;

Observable observer1 = Observable.just(1, 2, 3)
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());

Observable observer2 = observer1.map(new Func1<Integer, Integer>() {
    @Override
    public Integer call(Integer myint) {
        //multiples each int by 2
        return myint * 2;
    }
});

observer2.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());

observer2.subscribe(new Action1<Integer>() {
    @Override
    public void call(Integer i) {
        System.out.println("this is the Integer multiplied by two:" + i);
    }
});

System.out.println("I want this statement to come after multiplication completes");
```

I realize I can use the `onComplete` call back but that's not my point.  I am trying to figure out how I can block an observer until it completes and then continue with the rest of my code. At this moment the log looks like this:

> I/System.out﹕ I want this statement to come after multiplication completes
>      I/System.out﹕ this is the Integer multiplied by two:2
>      I/System.out﹕ this is the Integer multiplied by two:4
>      I/System.out﹕ this is the Integer multiplied by two:6

Also notice how I am observing and subscribing all on the MainThread, is this done by default if I don't specify?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want to block until an Observable completes use `observable.toBlocking().forEach()` instead of `subscribe()`.

```java
observer2
    .toBlocking()
    .forEach(new Action1<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public void call(Integer i) {
            System.out.println("this is the Integer multiplied by two:" + i);
        }
    });
```

There are a number of [Blocking Observable Operators](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Blocking-Observable-Operators) that can be used in addition to `forEach()` to obtain the desired effect. For example, if you only need the first item emitted then use `observable.toBlocking().first()`

Also, note that the RxJava API returns a new Observable for each of the calls you are making. Thus, the following line has no effect on the schedulers that observable2 uses.

```java
observer2.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
```

It does create a new Observable with the specified schedulers but throws it away since the returned Observable is not assigned to any variable. You could do the following instead.

```java
observer2
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .toBlocking()
    .forEach(new Action1<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public void call(Integer i) {
            System.out.println("this is the Integer multiplied by two:" + i);
        }
    });
```

Comment: For RxJava2 see http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#blockingForEach-io.reactivex.functions.Consumer- and other `blockingForX` methods